# Upgrading to Jetpack Compose Alpha 12 causes errors on setContent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose

I upgraded to Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha12 and started to run into issues.

Firstly, the `setContent` method I was using showed as deprecated.

From the [Alpha 12 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-alpha12), I noticed that it said:

> ComponentActivity.setContent has moved to androidx.activity.compose.setContent in the androidx.activity:activity-compose module. ([Icf416](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/Icf4168e6078b87ce746569a946b2a90274197c72))

So I removed my `import androidx.compose.ui.platform.setContent` and switched it to `import androidx.activity.compose.setContent`, which removed the deprecation.

However, I then got an error that says:

```
w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:
-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes
This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!
e: Classes compiled by an unstable version of the Kotlin compiler were found in dependencies.
Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xallow-unstable-dependencies' to suppress errors
e: /[my path]/MainActivity.kt: (39, 9): Class 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' is
compiled by an unstable version of the Kotlin compiler and cannot be loaded by this compiler
```

And again, I was able to work around that by changing my `build.gradle` file to have:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    useIR = true
    // I added this line
    freeCompilerArgs += "-Xallow-unstable-dependencies"
}
```

While that let me compile my app, I now get the following exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent(
Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Com
positionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;)V in class 
Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super classes
(declaration of 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in [my apk]
```

How can I fix this and upgrade my app to Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha12?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/179911234), this issue is related to the new `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha01` artifact.

From that issue:

> [Activity `1.3.0-alpha02`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.3.0-alpha02) has been released and fixes this issue.
>
> Apps using Compose alpha12 and specifically artifacts like `androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-alpha12` that internally use `setContent` should add the `activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha02` dependency to their `dependencies` block to ensure that the `1.3.0-alpha01` artifact is not used

So to fix your app, you should:

1. Remove the `freeCompilerArgs += "-Xallow-unstable-dependencies"` line from the `build.gradle` file (as it is no longer needed)
2. Add a specific dependency on Activity Compose `1.3.0-alpha02`:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

By adding that dependency, any direct usages of `setContent` as well as internal usages by `androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha12` or `androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-alpha12` will use the fixed Activity Compose 1.3.0-alpha02 release.

Comment: Hi, is there a resource somewhere that link all those changes together in a digestible manner ?

Answer (score 0):

With `Activity 1.3.0-alpha02`, `setContent` is working, but got another error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/AL2.0' from inputs:
```

Had to use the workaround to make it built

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
```

And still have the warning
`Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies`

Comment: If it isn't about `setContent`, then it really isn't an answer to this question, is it? It sounds like you're running into totally separate issues related to the move to Kotlin 1.4.3.0, namely [this Kotlin issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-debug#debug-agent-and-android) (unrelated to Compose) and the use of a no longer needed flag you've left behind.

Comment: You are right. Created another new question about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343654/upgrading-to-jetpack-compose-1-0-0-alpha12-with-kotlin-1-4-30-error