# Error finding jetpack compose compiler Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.0.0-alpha11

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Im getting this error in an android project.

```
Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.0.0-alpha11.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://maven.google.com/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-alpha11/compose-compiler-1.0.0-alpha11.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-alpha11/compose-compiler-1.0.0-alpha11.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.0.0-alpha11/compose-compiler-1.0.0-alpha11.pom
```

As you can see I have added the google repository based on the tutorials.

The build Gradle is configured like the following:

**build.gradle.kts**

```
dependencies {
val composeVersion = "1.0.0-alpha11"
//val composeVersion = "0.1.0-dev10"
implementation(project(":shared"))
//implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$composeVersion")
//implementation ("androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:$composeVersion")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2")


implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion")
// Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
//implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion")
// Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
implementation ("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion")
// Material Design
implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion")
// Material design icons
implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$composeVersion")
implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$composeVersion")
// Integration with observables
implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$composeVersion")
implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:$composeVersion")

 //UI Tests
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-alpha10'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion(29)
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.myTempOrg.myTestApp.androidApp"
    minSdkVersion(24)
    targetSdkVersion(29)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.4.21"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-alpha11"
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
    useIR = true
}
```

I have also tried downgrading to alpha03 which seems to be found, but get another host of issues there with missing dependencies.

Comment: Post your project `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

The kotlinCompilerVersion should be "1.4.21-2" with alpha 11.

Please note that alpha 12 is now out and you can upgrade using the following dependencies: [link to alpha 12 dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#declaring_dependencies)

You also need to add this: [link to further instructions for updating to alpha 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146595/5513788)