# Upgrading to Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha12 with Kotlin 1.4.30 error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After upgrading to Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha12 with Kotlin 1.4.30, also with [`Activity 1.3.0-alpha02` fix for `setContent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146595/3247270), but still got an error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/AL2.0' from inputs:
```

Had to use the workaround to make it built

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
```

And also have the warning
`Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies`

No matter keeping `freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies"]` under `kotlinOptions` or not

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed once upgrading to Compose `1.0.0-beta01`. No workaround needed.

Answer (score 0):

Once I upgraded to Compose 1.0.0-beta01, kotlin.collections such as arrayListOf, listOf, ... are not implicity imported anymore. Did it occur to you too ?

Comment: Your answer (question? :-)) is not related to the question author asked... However, I tried to answer your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369899/why-kotlin-collections-is-not-implicitly-imported-after-upgrading-to-jetpack-com/66404390#66404390

Answer (score 0):

You must use compatible versions of compose and Kotlin. Compose beta08 and Kotlin 1.5.10 are compatible