# The compose compiler plugin you are using (version 1.0.0-alpha13) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0-alpha13

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

I cannot get my project to compile after upgrading to compose beta-01. When searching for "alpha-13" in my project I cannot find something too, which is really weird. It worked with alpha-12 though. Im running the correct Android Studio (Arctic Fox Canary 8 at the time)

Invalidate Caches restart, clean project and cleaned global cache does not work

```
androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.IncompatibleComposeRuntimeVersionException: You are using an outdated version of Compose Runtime that is not compatible with the version of the Compose Compiler plugin you have installed. The compose compiler plugin you are using (version 1.0.0-alpha13) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0-alpha13.
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.outdatedRuntimeWithUnknownVersionNumber(VersionChecker.kt:102)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.check(VersionChecker.kt:67)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add compose runtime dependency.

```
dependencies {
    def compose_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I finally fixed it by declaring an explicit dependency on androidx.activity:activity-compose (similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146595/10319730)) in both my app module as well as my compose module, which the app module depends on. Before, I declared the activity compose dependency only in my compose module, not my app module.

This is what my setup looks like now:

```
// build.gradle (:app)
android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Versions.compose
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation project(':common-ui-compose')
    ...

    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Activity.activityCompose
```

```
// build.gradle (:common-ui-compose)
android {
    ...

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Versions.compose
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    ...
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Activity.activityCompose
```

Answer (score 4):

In a multi-module project with kts:

```
class MyLibraryPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        with(project) {
            plugins.all {
                dependencies {
                    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.1")//specify the version
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use this? can you add imports too?

Answer (score 2):

if you enable compose for all dependencies you must add this

```
implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$version")
```

for all module

you can see the versions in this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-runtime)

Answer (score -1):

In my case I rearranged files, added modules in a multi-module app and got this error.

As others, I also added `implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.6.2")` to 2 modules. Also updated `androidx.compose.animation` (with similar) to latest (1.6.2), `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` to 1.5.10. But it didn't help. After syncing Gradle I got other errors (forgot to add dependencies). After fixing various build errors, syncing Gradle, reopening the project it launched.

Then I removed `implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.6.2")` and reverted libraries versions.