# Migrate to Jetpack Compose in a multi-module app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose. I have already used it and everything worked fine. I have configured Compose in the app module and in a feature module and in both modules I have imported the same library (see below).
When I try to use it in another module, with the same configuration I get the error and all the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409744/the-compose-compiler-plugin-you-are-using-version-1-0-0-alpha13-expects-a-mini) do not apply:

> androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.IncompatibleComposeRuntimeVersionException:
> You are using an outdated version of Compose Runtime that is not
> compatible with the version of the Compose Compiler plugin you have
> installed. The compose compiler plugin you are using (version
> 1.0.0-rc01) expects a minimum runtime version of 1.0.0-rc01.  at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.outdatedRuntimeWithUnknownVersionNumber(VersionChecker.kt:113)
> at
> androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.VersionChecker.check(VersionChecker.kt:78)
> at
> androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:57)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:120)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:116)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:140)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:66)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:61)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)

> ...

I have added the following sections in the `build.gradle` file of the new module (as for the app module and the first module):

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Version.compose
        kotlinCompilerVersion Version.kotlin
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation Compose.runtime
    implementation Compose.composeActivity
    implementation Compose.ui
    implementation Compose.material
    implementation Compose.uiTooling
    implementation Compose.livedata
    androidTestImplementation Compose.uiTest
}
```

where

```
object Version {
    const val kotlin = "1.5.10"
    const val compose = "1.0.0-rc01"
    const val composeActivity = "1.3.0-rc01"
}

object Compose {
    const val runtime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:${Version.compose}"
    const val composeActivity = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${Version.composeActivity}"
    const val ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Version.compose}"
    const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:${Version.compose}"
    const val uiTooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Version.compose}"
    const val uiTest = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:${Version.compose}"
    const val livedata = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:${Version.compose}"
}
```

The second module in which I'm trying to add Jetpack Compose has many more dependencies.
Is it possible that the issue is with one of the dependencies?

Comment: It looks like it has got to do with the dependencies. If I use a third feature module everything is OK. It's only the `core` module with many dependencies that has problems

Comment: Your kotlin version is not compatable with your compose version. For kotlin version `1.5.10` use `1.0.0-beta09` compose version

Comment: @VygintasB I followed the setup suggested here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is some dependency in the same classpath as your compose dependencies that is bringing another outdated compose version transitively which could result in that failure. A helpful tool which can help you here is: https://github.com/JakeWharton/dependency-tree-diff

Also Note that compose is using a fixed kotlin version under the hood to get their compiler/runtime work, so check that also