# Upgrading to Android Studio (2020.3.1) Canary 15 causes Compose build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I upgraded to Android Studio (2020.3.1) Canary 15 and started to get compiler errors.

The error generated is

> e: This version (1.0.0-alpha13) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.30 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.32 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

App configuration versions are:

```
    ext {
        gms_version = "4.3.5"
        agp_version = '7.0.0-alpha15'
        ktlint_version = "10.0.0"
        kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
        detekt_version = "1.16.0"
        versions_version = "0.36.0"
        dagger_version = "2.34.1-beta"
        crashlytics_gradle_version = "2.5.2"
        sceneform_version = "1.17.1"
        nav_version = "2.3.5"
        compose_version = "1.0.0-beta05"
    }

dependencies {
...
    // Compose dependencies
    implementation composeDependencies.composeUi
    implementation composeDependencies.composeTooling
    implementation composeDependencies.composeFoundation
    implementation composeDependencies.composeMaterial
    implementation composeDependencies.composeViewModel
    implementation networkDependencies.retrofit
    }
```

I have looked a similar issue that talk about this [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146595/1287082), but it doesn't seem relevant in my case since I am not using a Compose activity.

Comment: As they are telling you change kotlin version to 1.4.30 you are using  kotlin_version = "1.4.32"

Comment: go to project structure and change the Gradle build (alpha 12 works from me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downgrade to 1.4.30 or you can add a compiler option to ignore the warning

```
kotlinOptions {
    val options = listOf(
        "-P",
        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
    )
    freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + options
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, what i did was change in build.gradle:

`"classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5"`

to

`"classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"`

Answer (score 4):

Android note :
[image: Change the kotlin gradle plugin version in the build.gradle Project:]

In the `buildscript > dependencies` :

> Change `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5"`
>
> To `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"`

I put 1.4.30 cause in my case didn't works on 1.4.32.

Link from info in this tutorial : [Layouts in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle-io21%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dio21-resources%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#1)

Comment: yep or version 1.4.32 (... any what you use before update to 1.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this script under the project level module and **Sync** Gradle project.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        //...
        kotlin_version = '1.4.30'
    }
    //...
    dependencies {
        //...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```